# Lifetime bound on generic parameter not required on impl block

Tags: rust

I have a simple Wrapper that holds a reference to a slice of type `T`. My first attempt looked like this:

```
struct SliceWrapper<'a, T> {
    a: &'a [T],
}
```

Now the compiler rightly complains that `T` may not live long enough. So I do what it suggests and add a lifetime bound to `T`. Thereby telling the compiler that all borrowed content within `T` outlives `'a`.

This is how my [final attempt](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1252f206bbb2375fe804&version=nightly) looks:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct SliceWrapper<'a, T: 'a> {
    a: &'a [T],
}

impl<'a, T> SliceWrapper<'a, T> {
    fn new(n: &'a [T]) -> SliceWrapper<'a, T> {
        SliceWrapper { a: n }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    let aw = SliceWrapper::new(&array[..2]);

    println!("{:?}", aw);
}
```

This works. But, if I changed the impl to

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> SliceWrapper<'a, T> {
    fn new(n: &'a [T]) -> SliceWrapper<'a, T> {
        SliceWrapper { a: n }
    }
}
```

it also works. Why don't I have to also specify the lifetime bound on the impl block? What is different from my first successful attempt where I omitted it on the impl block?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that defining

```
struct SliceWrapper<'a, T: 'a>
```

would implicitly force the bound `T: 'a` wherever you use `SliceWrapper`. So both are equivalent:

```
 impl<'a, T>     SliceWrapper<'a, T> // T: 'a is "contained" in SliceWrapper definition
 impl<'a, T: 'a> SliceWrapper<'a, T> // but it doesn't harm to say it again
```

This is just a feeling, not a well-proven assertion (I didn't check RFCs or compiler code). It would be consistent with what happens with type inference: you usually have to supply the type once, and can be implicit in most other places.

Comment: This makes sense. I guess the compiler complained, if I would violate the bound on the struct definition.

Comment: It would be inconsistent with trait bounds. If you have `struct Foo<T: Clone>(T);` you can't write `impl<T> Foo<T> {}`: it will complain about the trait bound not being satisfied. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c3eadc6db98c82d3e125813c21235485&version=stable&backtrace=0)